# How to create a customized Select.Item from native-base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using Select from native-base and I'm having problem with trying to customize the selectable options from Select.Item.

```
react-native: 0.70.5,
native-base": "^3.4.25
```

```
<Select>
<Select.Item value="one" label="one" />
</Select>
```

where it will only render the label, which expects a string. I am not able to render any other component from Select.Item

what I'm trying to achieve looks a lot like the picture below:

[Desired Select.Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANLxq.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: not a solution as it breaks the component value. You have to use leftIcon and rightIcon properties instead**

You can use the `label` attribute to customize the item content.

Something like:

```
<Select>
  <Select.Item 
    value="one" 
    label={
      <Row>
        <Icon as={MaterialCommunityIcons} name="information" />
        <Text>one</Text>
      </Row>
    }
  />
</Select>
```

In my opinion, the attribute name is misleading. You can also use `leftIcon` and `rightIcon` properties on `Select.Item`. If you can't achieve the customization level you want with these, I'm afraid you will have to create your own `Select` component based on [`ActionSheet`](https://docs.nativebase.io/action-sheet) elements.

Note that this will not be web compatible, so if you need web support it won't be an option. I'm also not sure to which extent other components are supported within this item element.

Comment: When i'm doing likeso, the Select value will not be shown, it seems like since the "label" prop only accepting string and is using it as the value for the Select

Comment: @AmaluddinAsyraf You are right, this makes the component unusable. I've been able to work around it using leftIcon and rightIcon properties instead.